# Send web-push using Node.js modules

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, web-push

I'm following this well documented page about sending a web-push:
https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push

But I'm using node.js in AWS Lambda in the new format, so it will be:

```
import ??? from "web-push";
```

How do I import the sendNotification function from web-push?

PS, using `import { sendNotification } from "web-push";`

results in:

```
Named export 'sendNotification' not found. The requested module 'web-push' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
```

Comment: If I used `import * as webpush from "web-push";` then `webpush.default.sendNotification(subscription, payload, options)` it is getting further, but now it's timing out, probably because i have attached the VPC, and so cannot reach the internet.